# How to have H1 for site title only on Homepage?

Tags: tags, headers

I´m using the Leaf Theme and in the header the following code can be found:

```
<?php $header_image = get_header_image();
                        if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) { ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                                <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" />
                            </a>
                        <?php } else { ?>

                        <hgroup>
                            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                            <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
                        </hgroup>

                        <?php } ?>
```

Right now the on all pages the site-title has the H1 tag and the site-description the H2 tag. I want this only on the homepage. On all other pages the title should have H6 and the description H7.

How can I do this?

*The first part of the code is for when you use an image instead of title/description. I included it because it is included in the php if*

Comment: AFAIK, there is no `<h7>` tag...

Answer (score 0):

This is one way...

```
<?php $headertag = ( is_front_page() ) ? 'h1' : 'h6'; ?>
<hgroup>
    <<?php echo $headertag; ?> class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></<?php echo $headertag; ?>>
    <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
</hgroup>
```

Comment: and a great way - it works!